# Memory leak running Apache Thrift server

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jmx, thrift

I'm running a Java server using Apache Thrift and profiling it I found memory (Old Gen) is always growing, as shown by this graph:

[image: jconsole]

The sharp drop at the end of the graph is because I clicked "Perform GC".

I understand there's a memory leak here. So I ran a leak detector ([MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)) and it reported as follows:

[image: MAT report]

> One instance of "com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ArrayNotificationBuffer"
>   loaded by "" occupies 7,844,208 (77.22%) bytes.

I never use this class myself, so I assume Apache Thrift uses this internally. I also found that `ArrayNotificationBuffer` memory leak [this actually is an old known fixed JDK bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6957378).

So I have a some questions about this:

1. Why when I click "Perform GC" there's such a drop in the allocated memory? Isn't the GC ran automatically the same? Why it doesn't garbage-collect this memory then?
2. I use OpenJDK (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2) and [as far as I can see](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22arraynotificationbuffer%22) all bugs relating to `ArrayNotificationBuffer` are quite old and fixed, so why is this happening? How to fix it?

Comment: A quick search revealed no occurrences of `ArrayNotificationBuffer` in the Thrift sources.

Comment: @JensG I think I was wrong, the JMX is actually used natively by the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the allocation was cleared when you ran GC() just means a legitimate chunk of memory that would eventually have been released. If your heap is large and other allocation requests  do not fail, old gen could be deferred for a while.

As for the buffer, I would speculate that a JMX notification listener was registered but is not handling emitted notifications in a timely manner, but it's hard to say.

Comment: Ok, I understand freeing old gen could be delayed, but delayed for almost 2 days? What for? What use are obsolete objects? Any idea how to fix the JMX leak?

Comment: A 70 MB old gen is fairly mundane, in my view, unless you're running a seriously resource limited environment. Default heap space for [server] JVM's is typically in the 1GB area, so I don't think this is an anomalous state.

Comment: Yes, right, heap is 1 GiB. Ok I got it, thanks, what about the JMX? I think the JMX is JVM's, not Thrift's, but I don't know how to configure or disable this...

Comment: Weeellll....  it could just be your jconsole instance. Was that running straight for 2 days as well ? jconsole registers some number of notification listeners by default. Try a fresh instance of your server and don't use jconsole. Eyeball the stats using jstat (same core protocol as jconsole but without the UI, so does not register any listeners, or fewer at least....). My optimistic guess is that you will not see that large notif buffer.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking to do the same, thanks for the insights, I will try this and report back here, thanks again!